# Is there a fractional derivative that preserves the composition of the one-parameter Mittag-Leffler function with $x\mapsto x^{\alpha}$?

Tags: differential-equations, fractals, fractional-calculus, applied-mathematics

Let $\alpha\in (0,1)$. The Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ is defined by
$$ \sideset{_0^R}{}{D^{\alpha}f(t)}
=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(1-\alpha)}}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{0}^{t}
\frac{f(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha}}ds\right).$$
And the Caputo fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ is defined by

$$ \sideset{_0^C}{}{D^{\alpha}f(t)}
=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(1-\alpha)}}
\int_{0}^{t}
\frac{f^{\prime}(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha}}ds.$$

Obviously, the two derivatives coincide when $f\in C^{1}(0,+\infty)$ and the integrals exist. In this case we will simply denote the fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ by $D^{\alpha}$.

Recall the well-known Mittag-Leffler function  $E_{\alpha}$ which is an entire function given by the series
$$E_{\alpha}(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha k}}{\Gamma{(\alpha k+1)}},\quad x\in \mathbb{C}.$$

Now, one can check that
$$D^{\alpha}E_{\alpha}(x^{\alpha})=E_{\alpha}(x^{\alpha})+D^{\alpha}1.$$
Note that
$$D^{\alpha}1=\frac{t^{-\alpha}}{\Gamma{(1-\alpha)}}.$$

I understand there are many definitions for fractional derivatives. Has any one encountered a definition for $D^{\alpha}$ for which
$$D^{\alpha}E_{\alpha}(x)=E_{\alpha}(x).$$
That would make solving the simple fractional problem $D^{\alpha}u=Au$ with $u(0)=u_0$, $A\in \mathbb{C}$, very easy. It would be simply $u(t)=E_{\alpha}(At^{\alpha})u_{0}$.